React Native: Image pop-up (lazy loading) on first run despite using prefetched local images
I'm seriously stuck on a bug in my RN Expo app and I cannot possibly fathom what I'm doing wrong.
For the last two days I've been trying to fix the bug that makes all of my images pop-up about half a second after rendering my pages when the user enters them for the first time after booting/reloading the app.
At first, I thought that the reason for it might be that the images I'm using are too big so I've temporarily, for debugging purposes, replaced them with small webps that I have alredy used in another project without any problems. This turned out to not be the case.
Then, I've tried pre-fetching my images using the code provided in Expo docs. This changed nothing, whatsoever.
I've also, after seeing such suggestion in another thread, made a development build to see if it would fix it - it did not.
Here is the link to my repo on GitHub if anyone wants to take a look: https://github.com/irolinski/Well_CBT
Here's a gif of how the bug looks like: https://gifyu.com/image/SyL5p
Here are the two components that I was focusing on: the second one is just a random one that I've added images to.
_layout.tsx
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useColorScheme } from "@/hooks/useColorScheme";
import { Provider as StateProvider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "@/state/store";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { Asset } from "expo-asset";

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

function cacheImages(images: any[]) {
  return images.map((image) => {
    if (typeof image === "string") {
      return Image.prefetch(image);
    } else {
      return Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync();
    }
  });
}

export default function RootLayout() {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Inter: require("../assets/fonts/Inter-Standard.ttf"),
    InterItalic: require("../assets/fonts/Inter-Italic.ttf"),
    KodchasanRegular: require("../assets/fonts/Kodchasan-Regular.ttf"),
    KodchasanMedium: require("../assets/fonts/Kodchasan-Medium.ttf"),
  });

  const [imagesLoaded, setImagesLoaded] = useState(false);

  // Load any resources or data that you need before rendering the app
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadResourcesAndDataAsync() {
      try {
        SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

        const imageAssets = cacheImages([
          require("../assets/images/affirmation-images/California-backyard-1.webp"),
          require("../assets/images/affirmation-images/California-backyard-2.webp"),
          require("../assets/images/affirmation-images/California-backyard-3.webp"),
          require("../assets/images/affirmation-images/California-backyard-4.webp"),
          require("../assets/images/affirmation-images/english-countryside-1.webp"),
          require("../assets/images/affirmation-images/english-countryside-2.webp"),
          require("../assets/images/affirmation-images/english-countryside-3.webp"),
          require("../assets/images/affirmation-images/english-countryside-4.webp"),
        ]);

        await Promise.all([...imageAssets]);
        console.log("images cached");
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
      } finally {
        setImagesLoaded(true);
        SplashScreen.hideAsync();
      }
    }

    loadResourcesAndDataAsync();
  }, []);

  if (!imagesLoaded || !fontsLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <StateProvider store={store}>
      <GestureHandlerRootView>
        <Stack>
          <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="tools/classic_cbt/cda"
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="tools/classic_cbt/journal"
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="tools/relax/breathing"
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="tools/distract/phone"
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="+not-found" />
        </Stack>
      </GestureHandlerRootView>
    </StateProvider>
  );
}

app/(tabs)/Tools.tsx
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import FrameMenu from "@/components/FrameMenu";
import Text from "@/components/global/Text";
import ToolCard from "../../components/ToolCard";

const Tools = () => {
   return (
    <FrameMenu title="Tools">
      <View>
        <Text className="mb-8 mt-2 text-left text-2xl">Classic</Text>
        <ToolCard
          name="Identify the Distortions"
          image={require("@/assets/images/affirmation-images/english-countryside-1.webp")}
          link={"/tools/classic_cbt/cda"}
        />
        <ToolCard
          name="Mood Journal"
          image={require("@/assets/images/affirmation-images/english-countryside-2.webp")}
          link={"/tools/classic_cbt/journal"}
        />
        <ToolCard
          name="Ground Yourself"
          image={require("@/assets/images/affirmation-images/english-countryside-3.webp")}
          link={"tools/classic_cbt/grounding"}
        ></ToolCard>
        <Text className="mb-8 mt-2 text-left text-2xl">Relax</Text>
        <ToolCard
          name="Breathing excercises"
          link={"/tools/relax/breathing"}
          image={require("@/assets/images/affirmation-images/english-countryside-4.webp")}
        />
        <ToolCard
          name="Muscle relaxation"
          link={"/tools/relax/muscleRelaxation"}
          image={require("@/assets/images/affirmation-images/english-countryside-1.webp")}
        />
        <Text className="mb-8 mt-2 text-left text-2xl">Distract yourself</Text>
        <ToolCard
          name="Phone to a friend"
          image={require("@/assets/images/affirmation-images/english-countryside-1.webp")}
          link={"/tools/distract/phone"}
        />
        <ToolCard
          name="Listen to music"
          link={"/tools/distract/music"}
          image={require("@/assets/images/affirmation-images/english-countryside-1.webp")}
        />
      </View>
    </FrameMenu>
  );
};

export default Tools;

